# QGIS Y-Axis grid repeating values

Tags: qgis, print-composer, latitude-longitude, globe

I've set up a grid on a map in print layout. The X-axis labels are working correctly but the y axis is repeating the results:
[image]

The options selected are shown in the following two photos:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your base map is probably in  3857 Pseudo Mercator CRS or something like that where you want to frame it and have a grid on a Lat/Lon WGS84 4326 CRS.

In that case, QGIS layouts has hard times deriving consistent coordinates on the edges (for map coordinates to geometrically form a grid, the grid projection and the map projection need to be similar).

See below, same issue as the one you have + weird artifacts on the top and bottom frames, when the **Map item** CRS is set as 3857 Pseudo Mercator:

[image]

If you change the properties of the **Map item** to be WGS84/4326, in line with the grid CRS, it works fine:

[image]